# Why is my class size appending an extra byte?

Tags: c++

I have the following class structure:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
class Base{ 
   Base(){}
    ~Base{}
    void accept();
};

class A : Base{
    int m1;
    int m2;
    int m3;
};

class B : Base{
    A a;
    int m1;
    int m2;
    int m3;
    int m4;
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

Size of B in this case is 29 bytes.

However, when I make class A not inherit from Base, but B still inherits from Base, Class B becomes 28 bytes.

Then if I make class A inherit from Base but B not inherit from base Class B also becomes 28 bytes.

So only when both A and B inherit from Base does my class B's size go from 28 -> 29 bytes.

What is happening that would cause this behavior?

Comment: `B` has 2 distinct `Base` (one from inheritance, one from member `a`) which should not share address.

Comment: You might change place of `A a;` to not be first member and size of B would be 28 bytes again.

Comment: try [`[[no_unique_address]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/no_unique_address)

Comment: In my experience, adding a `char[0]` member to empty classes is portable between real-world compilers.

Comment: @o11c Unless you use `-pedantic-errors`. But what use would it be to add such member?

Comment: @phuclv: Change nothing [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/74o7zW4Yc) (msvc already does a packing [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jfveeqKWW) without).

Comment: @o11c we are dumping data to shared memory and need the data in the same order with the inheritance structure in tact this hack actually saves me a lot of refactoring.  My b class is now the expected 28 bytes.

Comment: @Jarod42: I think you have to put the attribute on the potentially-empty object (base subobject of type `Base`) not on `A a;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C++ object model doesn't allow two distinct subobjects of the same type to exist at the same address.

https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#9

> Two objects with overlapping lifetimes that are not bit-fields may have the same address if one is nested within the other, or if at least one is a subobject of zero size and they are of different types; otherwise, they have distinct addresses and occupy disjoint bytes of storage.

Here your two subobjects `(B::Base)b` and `(A::Base)(b.a)` both have zero size, but they are not of different types, therefore they require distinct addresses.

Comment: The standard also disallows everything that `#pragma pack(push, 1)` does do (i.e. it cause members to exist in misaligned addresses), so it's not necessarily obvious that this rule wouldn't also be ignored by it.

Comment: @eerorika: I don't agree that unaligned members are forbidden by the Standard on systems where alignment is a performance issue and does not affect correctness.

Comment: `alignment requirements ... place restrictions on the addresses at which an object of that type may be allocated. An alignment ... representing the number of bytes between successive addresses at which a given object can be allocated. An object type imposes an alignment requirement on every object of that type` - `The lifetime of an object of type T begins when: storage with the proper alignment and size for type T is obtained, and
...` There's only one way that I would interpret the standard, and it doesn't allow for existence of misaligned objects.

Comment: If alignment requirement (i.e. what you get with `alignof`) of the types were 1, then you wouldn't need `#pragma pack(push, 1)`. There is no concept of "natural alignment" in the standard.

Comment: That's not what the standard says. It says: `The result of the alignof operator reflects the alignment requirement of the type` - `An alignof expression yields the alignment requirement of its operand type.
`

Comment: @eerorika: Yes the verbiage is weird.  "alignment requirement" is not actually required.  Your earlier comment mentions "proper alignment", which is the thing that actually is required.  On systems which support unaligned access, the results of `#pragma pack(1)` are still "proper alignment" even though it is not the fundamental or natural alignment of the type, as reported by `alignof(T)`.

Comment: Moreover what about https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.align#2 : "**The alignment required for a type may be different when it is used as the type of a complete object and when it is used as the type of a subobject.**"  That breaks your simple model of "one alignment requirement per type, returned by `alignof(T)`"

Comment: Fundamental alignment is `alignof(std::max_align_t)`. It's not an alignment that associated with any particular type. It's just an alignment that is guaranteed to be strict enough to satisfy the alignment requirement of all scalar types. I don't see how this is relevant to `#pragma pack(push, 1)`

Comment: `The alignment required for a type may be different when it is used as the type of a complete object and when it is used as the type of a subobject.` Yeah, the example following the rule demonstrates why that is. It's because virtual base objects may be stored outside their derived object, in which case its alignment won't affect the derived sub object. The rules still apply in every other case outside of the exception. The wording is quite general though and perhaps it could be interpreted to allow implementation to have any alignment for any member. I wonder whether it's intentional.